# Thunderbird Enigmail does not recognize key - "error - no matching/private key found"

Tags: pgp, openpgp, enigmail

A few month ago I set up enigmail for one of my computers. I imported a fried's key and was successful in decrypting his messages.

I switched computers now and tried to replicate all the steps I did the first time for the new computer. (I say replicate because I am not too involved with computer security, or computers in general and sometimes struggle to understand the exact reason behind the individual steps. If it is somehow relevant, I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hy3_duCVogY).

Now when I try to decrypt his messages on the new computer I get the following 
`Error - no matching/private key found to decrypt message`. However, when I go to the key manager I can clearly see that I imported his key (and I re-tried this step several times).

One possible source of the problem I identified:
When I right-click on my friend's email address and try to `create enigmail rule from address` it does not identify his key. I can then click select key and select his key. However, when I press ok, close and reopen the window, I will find myself at the very beginning and enigmail still does not seem to be able to link the person's key with his email address.

Has anyone had similar problems? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you "trusted" the imported key? I haven't specifically used enigmail but cleopatra won't let you use a key unless you've marked it as a certain level of trust(by signing it with your own key if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Good suggestion. I have set the level of trust and signed the key but it still does not work. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not that you don't have his public key on the new machine, it's that you don't have your private key on the new machine. You need your private key to decrypt messages that are sent to you encrypted with your public key. His public key is for when you want to send him encrypted messages.